# Why was my question about OCR closed?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, closed-questions, reopen-closed

My question has over 12 votes and it has over 5 answer and people getting involved, and I think it would be interesting to find solution for this, but it was closed by a moderator.

Can you please reopen the question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971941/ocr-with-colors

Comment: How is that question related to programming? (And, as an aside: please use proper uppercasing in your posts.)

Comment: Are you asking how to do it programmatically? It doesn't sound like it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek yes, but i thought i should write OCR, it easily explains the type of task, i guess i have to edit the question title and little description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The moderator who closed it as off topic made it quite clear in her comment why she did so:

> It wasn't clear from the question that it was looking for a programming solution. It picked up a couple flags to that effect and I agreed.

So, other users flagged it as not being a programming question, and the moderator acted on that.

If you want it reopened, you should edit the question first. Messy though, as some answers are already not about programming either. Heck, even the answer you gave the bounty is not about programming.

Comment: Ok if its looking for software to do something wouldn't that be for SuperUser then?

Comment: @Arjan thanks for advice, i would defo change the title and description.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason...

Questions of the following type

> How do I perform some massively complex task I have done no research and have no clues

are actively discouraged here.  We expect questions that can be *reasonably answered* by our users.  Obviously, the only way to answer this question is with something like

> Here's my product which does what you want! http://example.com

In other words, it spawns a list of different frameworks which seek to whittle down at the problem and attracts spammers who are only interested in hawking their products.  These types of answers we *also* wish to discourage, as they are low quality, and usually become worthless over time as the links rot or the frameworks are abandoned.